# If condition in HTML email template not working. Weird

Tags: email-template, if

I have a HTML email template with IF loop which is not working.

```
{!IF(NOT(ISNULL(pba__Closing__c.Buildings_survey_booked_To__c)),' to '+pba__Closing__c.Buildings_survey_booked_To__c,' ')}
```

There is  another IF condition in same template and it works fine.

```
{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(pba__Closing__c.Surveyor__c)),'<b>Surveyor / Company: </b>'+pba__Closing__c.Surveyor__c+'<br /><br />',' ')}
```

the Surveyor__c field is id field whereas the Buildings_survey_booked_To__c is Time field.

Can anyone spot the mistake....? The result of first if condition is always blank. but weird part is in 1st IF condition if i replace the Buildings_survey_booked_To__c field with other field...its works fine :)

Comment: Did you try changing ISNULL with ISBLANK?

Comment: Yes i tried ISNULL ISBLANK and event !=Null !=''   Nothing works

Comment: Are you sure that Does Buildings_survey_booked_To__c has a value?  If you display the field in the template by itself, what value is shown?